# react-beautiful-dnd: Cannot find drag handle element inside of Draggable

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-tsx, react-beautiful-dnd

I have a component that receives two sets of data and is a 
[react-beautiful-dnd](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd) `DragDropContext` as below

```
 render() {
    let index = -1;
    const dataSetOne = this.props.store!.getdata(1);
    const dataSetTwo = this.props.store!.getData(2);
    const allData = this.props.anotherStore!.getAllData();

    return (
        <DragDropContext onDragEnd={this.onDragEnd}>
          <Droppable droppableId="SIDE_MENU" direction="vertical" type="sections">
            {(provided, snapshot) => (
              <div
                {...provided.droppableProps}
                ref={provided.innerRef}
                onScroll={(e) => e.currentTarget.scrollTop}
              >
                {dataSetOne!.map((a, i) => {
                  index = i;
                  const currentData:any= allData.filter(/*logic*/)
                  return (
                    <MyDraggableComp
                      key={a.id!}
                      aes={a}
                      index={index}
                      data={currentData}
                    />
                  );
                })}
               {dataSetTwo.length > 0 ? (
                <MyDraggableComp
                  key="SOMEKEY"
                  aes={null}
                  index={index + 1}
                  data={dataSetTwo}
                />
                ) : null}
                {provided.placeholder}
              </div>
            )}
          </Droppable>
        </DragDropContext>
    );
  }
```

up to now, this code is working perfectly and The `MyDraggableComp` is implemented correctly regarding the dnd implementation guideline and contains the `{...sectionProvided.dragHandleProps}`

now have changed backend and `dataSetTwo` is never null or empty so wanted to remove the condition and always render it.

but moving the `dataSetTwo>0` condition and just have

```
            <MyDraggableComp
              key="SOMEKEY"
              aes={null}
              index={index + 1}
              data={dataSetTwo}
            />
```

***causes this error that I do not even understand the relation to the case and what to search for? can someone explain to me what is happening and how to fix it?***

```
Error: Invariant failed: 
      Cannot find drag handle element inside of Draggable.
      Please be sure to apply the {...provided.dragHandleProps} to your Draggable

      More information: https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd#draggable

▼ 21 stack frames were expanded.
invariant
node_modules/tiny-invariant/dist/tiny-invariant.esm.js:11
getDragHandleRef
node_modules/react-beautiful-dnd/dist/react-beautiful-dnd.esm.js:6165
DragHandle.componentDidMount
node_modules/react-beautiful-dnd/dist/react-beautiful-dnd.esm.js:7351
commitLifeCycles
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15961
commitAllLifeCycles
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17262
HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:149
invokeGuardedCallbackDev
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:199
invokeGuardedCallback
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:256
commitRoot
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17458
completeRoot
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18912
performWorkOnRoot
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18841
performWork
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18749
performSyncWork
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18723
batchedUpdates$1
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18936
reactionScheduler
node_modules/mobx/lib/mobx.module.js:3626
runReactions
node_modules/mobx/lib/mobx.module.js:3602
.
.
.
```

Comment: did you pass {...provided.dragHandleProps} into the Draggable component which is imported from react-beautiful-dnd ?

Comment: can you show your Draggable component?  you should have   {...provided.droppableProps} to your Draggable as well.

Answer (score 5):

This is specific to react-beautiful-dnd and your version of styled-components - but did you see this warning in your console?:

```
The "innerRef" API has been removed in styled-components v4 in favor of React 16 ref forwarding, use "ref" instead like a typical component. "innerRef" was detected on component "styled.div".
```

I changed the api in my Draggable/Droppable to use `ref` over `innerRef` and it worked...